# Orient db Query for getting Sample db Grateful Dead Concerts data in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am new to OrientDB and Jasper reports. I have successfully connected the Jasper-soft studio with OrientDB using jdbc driver

[image]

But when I query the sample OrientDB Grateful Dead Concerts in Jasper reports, it returns some fields and their class type is `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument` but I am unable to read those fields' values and getting an error that it can not find this class. I think I am not writing a proper query.

Please it will be great help if someone can provide me the solution. Thank you

Comment: Can you write the query? Which version of orientDb? thx

Comment: Hi, Thank you . I am using 2.1.7 community edition of orient db and query is simple and basic. SELECT FROM E, Where E is a class of edge.

Comment: Actually when i use the same query in orientdb it shows results in this format( Please see the screen-shot link). Thee are 3 properties. One is just integer type and i can access it,s data in jaspersoft but other two fields are some kind of rids to other vertices. I can not access these two fields data. I want to get these two vertices data too with edges. Hee is the link to screen-shot (http://i.stack.imgur.com/0HHg8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields are of class `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument`, you need to declare them as so

```
<field name="out" class="com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument"></field>
```

To avoid **"class not found"** you need to included the library (.jar) holding this class [orientdb-core-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar](http://orientdb.com/download/) and all other jar's that it is referencing (see distribution).

To include a jar in **jaspersoft-studio**

> Each report is supposed to be part of a project. The project has a
>   classpath, and here is where you should add the jars you need.
>
> To add jar open the projects view and right click the project folder
>   with which you are working on. By default, new reports are created in
>   the project My Reports.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have resolved the error by following your instructions. But now when i add the out field to a report page to show the data is is giving another error. Here is the error.                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument
 at Blank_A4_1451541292746_568150.evaluate(Blank_A4_1451541292746_568150:182)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:277)

Comment: Show the (jr)xml of you textElement

Comment: The report you are generating is a jrxml file.... if you look it is actually an xml file (textfile), try to past some relevant parts of it in the question (edit your question adding the content of your jrxml file)

Comment: Here is the jrxml of a text element. <textField>
    <reportElement x="240" y="35" width="100" height="30" uuid="78203307-7b90-4671-8b9b-71de01480915"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{out}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Comment: I think you have it now.

Comment: Please help me, I am really stuck here.

Comment: I have never worked with OrientDB but if your field is of class ODocument and not null, you should try to output something that can be a String..., from http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/ODocument.html, I found different metods... I have edit the question to included one. Try the code above and tell me what happens...

Comment: It is still generating error. Error Evaluating expression for source text: $F{out}

Comment: Anyways thank you for you effort. I will do some search and will try myself. Thank a lot again.

Comment: @FarrukhCheema have you tried my edit... pass the stacktrace

Comment: Yes i tried your edit. But it is not the issue. Issue is in my query.

Comment: It was generating error again. But i got to know that my query was not correct and i need to know the orientdb query

Comment: I have solved the issue as i was not writing a proper query.